# Android - Dynamic data available on server not able to retrieve via Volley

Tags: android, ajax, android-volley

I have one `html` page that I am updating on some interval via `Ajax`. This page data I am trying to retrieve in a android application using Volley in a dialog box. Instead of loading all the data available in html body, it just retrieve static data.

**File 1. html file.**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    var request;
    window.onload = sendInfo;
    function sendInfo()
    {
      var v=3;
      var url="index.jsp?val="+v;

      if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
           request=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else if(window.ActiveXObject){
           request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      try
      {     
         request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;
         request.open("GET",url,true);      
         request.send(null);
         setTimeout("sendInfo()", 1000); // loading same screen after 1 sec
     }
     catch(e)
     {
         alert("Unable to connect to server");
     }
 }

 function getInfo(){
    if(request.readyState==4){
       var val=request.responseText;
       document.getElementById('data').innerHTML=val;
 }
}

</script>
</head>
 <body> 
   <p>this is static data</p>
   <span id="data"> </span>
 </body>
</html>
```

**File 2. jsp file.**

```
 <%
    double n = Math.random();
    out.print(n+"<br>");
 %>
```

above codes are running in tomcat server and page is getting refreshed in every second.

**Android Part** :

**MainActivity.java**

```
    url is address of html mentioned above. 

   final  ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response.toString());
           // String parsedText =response.toString().substring(500);
            String parsedText = doc.body().text();
            pDialog.setMessage(parsedText);
          //  pDialog.hide();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.setMessage(error.getMessage());
            // pDialog.hide();
        }
    });


 In emulator it is loading only static data of html file "this is static 
 data" . If I try to load complete response string, in that case value of span(commented above - // String parsedText =response.toString().substring(500);) is blank, though in browser debug mode I am able to see its value getting updated every second.
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong here. If my approach is wrong then please suggest any better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the mistake 
String parsedText = doc.body()**.text()**;
Correct
**String parsedText = doc.body()*.toString*;**

Comment: that way is commented already in previous line. I tried your suggestion - it is giving this output - <body> 
<p>this is static data</p>
 <span id="data"> </span>
</body>